# Duplicate class found in module error when runnig app uses firebase ml kit

Tags: android, firebase, ocr, firebase-machine-learning

I am developing android application that uses firebase ml kit to recognize text from image after importing firebase libraries when i run the application I catch this error:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzf found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzg found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzi found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzv found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzw found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

here is my dependency in build gradle(Module : app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.0.3'

}
```

and my build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: no , unfortunately I didn't